# How to make a 2x2 Table with the Top Row and the Right Column merged?

Tags: html, css, anki

How do I make a table with these proportions in CSS/HTML? (Could the cells also be flex shrink/grow?)

I'm trying to make it so that the tags will go around the sources in the bottom left, let me know if using a table isn't the right way to do this. [image]

Comment: what is your code ?What have you tried?  how is that supposed to be filled ? There is possible funny tricks, but not with flex nor grid.

Comment: I don't really have any code, I'm using a software called anki and I'm just trying to format my fields in this way so the Text in the Field 'Tags' wraps around the 'sources' field in the bottom left corner. What kind of tricks would you suggest?

Comment: Did you try to search for « table generator html » [?](https://divtable.com/generator/)

Comment: this kind https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PozbPLo inspired from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HKEpo

Comment: This works really well, thank you @G-Cyrillus, is there any way to make the #myFunnyBox text start in the bottom right?

Comment: Do you mean window's bottom right? Or is it #bottomed ? If the second, make it float right.

Comment: No it's the field outside the #bottomed field, the one in the blue square

Comment: Sorry I meant moving the text within the blue square to the bottom right, not the blue square itself

Comment: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PozbPLo ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, this community is amazing!